# Is a 50mm or 18-108mm lens most appropriate for a clothing photoshoot?

Tags: lens, lighting, product-photography, clothing

I am doing a photoshoot of a model wearing clothes for an online store. White backdrop, decent lighting and unfortunately not too much space.

I have two lenses to pick from: Nikon fixed 50mm f1.8 or Nikon 18-105mm.

Which one is more advisable to make the most of the lighting and get sharper image and under which aperture setup?

Answer (score 2):

The lens doesn't matter. Either will be just fine, assuming you have enough room for the right framing with the 50mm (and if you don't, you probably want to rethink anyway). For a situation like this, you want to stop down to f/5.6 or f/8 or so. You'll get plenty of depth of field and either lens will be beyond any problems (and this isn't a situation which stresses the lens anyway). Neither lens will have a particular advantage. **It's all about the lighting setup.** You didn't ask about that, but you might want to as a separate question — or see existing question [How can I improve my clothing photography with a limited budget?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60660/how-can-i-improve-my-clothing-photography-with-a-limited-budget), which covers some of the territory (and even mentions the exact same lenses).

Comment: I completely agree. I just want to add that the lens' use might see some restriction by the backdrop in your shoot and whether it can cover everything on a wider angle lens. However, having a 50mm and a zoom that has more reach, I don't see this being a problem in a typical situation.